# ASP.NET MVC Data Access Patterns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

An ASP.NET MVC beginner here wanting to get some overview of correct patterns. I understand the basic concept of MVC:

View - displays data received from the controller
Controller - responds to ASP.NET requests to serve correct views
Model - deals with db layer

I do however have a question about which layer is supposed to be talking to the database (using Entity Framework here) to retrieve that data. As far as I understand Model layer is there purely to represent the data from the database, which can then be represented better in a ViewModel, which can be passed to to a View using a Controller. Is the ViewModel responsible for getting the data from EF (Entity Framework) or is it the Controller... or is it the Model?

I think my main source of confusion is between ViewModel, Model and Controller in terms of the data access.

If there are any articles that talk specifically about this, any links would be very appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Views vary, but IMHO: for simple apps the controller's action methods can do the DB interaction to create a (view) model instance to pass to the view. For larger apps the controller's actions just orchestrate a domain layer which itself uses the model to perform CRUD operations on the database to return a view model which the action passes to the view (or the domain layer returns some part of the model for the action to transform into a view model). But there is significant variation, often driven by team preference and domain complexity.

Comment: But: because so much of this is "it depends on context" and "in my opinions" this question is not a good fit for [SO].

Comment: We usually have two models, one for view and one or more for the db layer, using mapping between the two, DAL layer is separated out of the MVC environment.

Comment: This is what I'm finding - there are a lot of different patterns based on where I look. I would really like to see some best practices for medium size code bases for best reuse and least amount of pain :)

Comment: In areas like there really are no *Best* practices. There are a lot of *good* practice, but for there to be a best one there would need to be a singular ideal approach. But there are too many context dependent variables for a single right way.